# Java Minecraft Plugin

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm getting really weird errors, errors, I know shouldn't be happening.

Errors:

> Syntax error on token "}", delete this token On both lines.

```
package me.itunes89.test;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Test extends JavaPlugin{
    public final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");
    public static Test plugin;

    @Override
    public void onDisable(){
        PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile = this.getDescription();
        this.logger.info(pdfFile.getName() + " Has been disabled!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
        PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile = this.getDescription();
        this.logger.info(pdfFile.getName() + " Version " + pdfFile.getVersion() + " Has been enabled!"); //You
    }
} //Here

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args)
{
    Player player = (Player) sender;
    if (commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("sendme"))
    {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "Sent");
    }
    return false;
} // and here
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Delete the first } and add one to the end. Your closing the class then adding a method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have closed the class scope too early. You need to remove the line containing the brace:

```
} //Here
```

and instead move it to the end of the file.

Comment: And move it after the line that says `} // and here`

Comment: Theres one missing at the end

Comment: in eclipse assuming your using eclipse. Try using the format to ensure that everthing is indented correctly.  Also if this answer helped accept it as this question will quickly gather downvotes.